# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: So, err, anyone want to take a stab at interpreting these answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [During battle can I play a one-shot card?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/during-battle-can-i-play-a-one-shot-card)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the qualities of a successful beta testing session from the player's perspective?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13791/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-successful-beta-testing-session-from-the-players-pe)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Selling to external market in Brass, is benefit salary or cash?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13716/selling-to-external-market-in-brass-is-benefit-salary-or-cash)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [In Settlers of Catan: Explorers and Pirates, who gets the gold when the pirate is paid?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13726/in-settlers-of-catan-explorers-and-pirates-who-gets-the-gold-when-the-pirate-i)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Can you attack again after I decide not to block?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/can-you-attack-again-after-i-decide-not-to-block)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Hokusai and Bernice Mai timing](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/hokusai-and-bernice-mai-timing)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Missile rule clarification](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13761/missile-rule-clarification)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are there any cards that turn creatures into land?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/are-there-any-cards-that-turn-creatures-into-land)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Does a cafe card bonus apply to all players?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13627/does-a-cafe-card-bonus-apply-to-all-players)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can the Mermaids create towns with +1 shipping bonus?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/can-the-mermaids-create-towns-with-1-shipping-bonus)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---